# Localhost 3000! Tab does no close! React

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I was running react on port 3000, my terminal cleared everything before i got to stop the server!Now I cannot close the tab of localhost 3000! Its stuck!
i'm on a mac! Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Even i had faced the same issue, i was able to stop only after killing chrome in activity monitor